# SonarQube seems to be stuck in a restart loop

Tags: macos, sonarqube

We have a SonarQube 6.6.0.32724 service running on our OSX 10.13.6 build machine.
A week or so ago, the SonarQube service seems to have gotten screwed up.

Looking at the OSX system log, I see this repeated over and over and over...

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.sonar[xxxxxx]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.sonar): Service only ran for 0 seconds.  Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

Since the web GUI was still working, I downloaded the 153MB sonarqube_app.log.
It's full of :

```
Starting SonarQube...
SonarQube is already running.
```

I tried running "sonar.sh stop", and while it reported that SonarQube stopped, it's still respawning every 10 seconds.  This is causing our builds to take 4 times as long as normal.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I don't think this is a SonarQube issue. See also [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1156916/lots-of-mac-sierra-service-only-ran-for-0-seconds-log-errors) question.

Comment: That does look similar, but doesn't really have a solution.
For now, can somebody tell me how to just STOP the sonarcube process?
since "sonar.sh stop" didn't work, I'm not sure what else to try. (other than deleting some files and rebooting.)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://setapp.com/how-to/how-to-view-and-kill-processes-on-mac) can help you.

Comment: I ended up having to use launchctl to disable sonar, and reboot the system.
THEN I re-enabled it, rebooted the system, and it stopped respawning continuously.
sadly, our builds are still running very slow for no apparent reason.